# Select Oracle with Selenium - java

Tags: java, oracle, selenium-webdriver

I need to fill a screen field with a data from the database .
I have `ObterConexao` class that connects to the database and returns on island as I need , but I can not use the main class which has the main project the data from the database to populate the next field `driver.findElement(By.name("iccid")).sendKeys("");`

`ObterConexao` class:

```
package criacaoMassa;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Statement;

public class ObterConexao {
    private static Connection ObterConexao() {
        Connection conexao = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:Bank", "user", "password");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conexao;
    }

    protected static ArrayList PegaSimCard(int quantidade) throws SQLException{
        int cont = 0;
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();

        Connection conexao = ObterConexao();
        Statement statement = (Statement) conexao.createStatement();


        String query = "(SELECT a.rp_package_value AS ICCID, c.rrs_resource_value AS IMSI,(  CASE WHEN (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 1) = SUBSTR (a.rp_package_value, 9, 1)) AND (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 2) <> '00') THEN 'Valid'  ELSE 'Invalid' END ) AS IMSI_CHECK , rrs_resource_sts Status, rp_package_sts FROM mtaapp8.rm_packages a, mtaapp8.rm_package_content b, mtaapp8.rm_resource_stock c WHERE a.rp_package_value IN (SELECT RRS_RESOURCE_VALUE FROM mtaapp8.rm_resource_stock c WHERE c.rrs_resource_tp_id = 6 AND c.rrs_resource_pool = 30   AND SUBSTR (RRS_RESOURCE_VALUE, 9, 2) like '10' AND c.rrs_resource_sts = 'ASSIGNED' ) AND a.rp_package_id = b.rpc_package_id AND c.rrs_resource_sts = a.rp_package_sts AND b.rpc_component_tp_id = 5 AND b.rpc_component_vl_id = c.rrs_id  AND (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 2) <> '00') AND (SUBSTR (c.rrs_resource_value, 6, 1) = SUBSTR (a.rp_package_value, 9, 1))) ";


        ResultSet resultSet = ((java.sql.Statement) statement).executeQuery(query);


        while (resultSet.next() && cont < quantidade) {
            lista.add(resultSet.getString(1));
            cont++;
        }
        System.out.println(PegaSimCard(5));
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
package criacaoMassa;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import criacaoMassa.geraCPF;



public class CriacaoMassa extends ObterConexao{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/paulo.roberto/Documents/eclipse/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
          DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
          caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
          WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

            driver.get("url");


            driver.findElement(By.name("iccid")).sendKeys("");

    }  


}
```

If there is an easier and cleaner to pick up this data bank and fill the field , suggestions are welcome...I use Oracle.

Comment: You haven't told us what the actual problem or error is, just "I can not use the main class"

Comment: @AndrewRegan 
I can not fill the uestão emq field with select data, can not interact with the class method , ObetrConexao

Comment: Could you post any errors / stacktraces you get?